# If function javascript not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm a total javascript noob and I'm just trying to bludgeon my way through this simple project. Whats supposed to happen is the script is only meant to run while y <= 3. Each time that it runs the second IF statement, it's meant to add one to y's count and if it runs the ELIF, it's meant to subtract one from y's count. The goal is so that you can only have 3 "selected" pictures at any one time. My y does definitely change, but the IF (y <= 3) does not seem to stop the program from running. Thanks in advance, Jack

```
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    var y = 4; //this is a counter

     function swapRoast() { //This defines the function
          var x=document.images; //this automatically creates an array of all the images in the document starting with image0 and assigns them to variable'x'

          if (y <= 3); { //this should check that y <= 3 before running

             if (x[0].src.match('Roast_Vegetables.png')) //This tests if the source of image0 in the array matches the script
             {
             x[0].src=('Roast_Vegetables_Selected.png'); //If the source matches, then it is changed
             y ++; //should add 1 to the y count
             }

             else if  (x[0].src.match('Roast_Vegetables_Selected.png')) //If the source doesn't match, then it tests a different source
             {
             x[0].src=('Roast_Vegetables.png'); //If the different source matches, then the script operates in reverse to the original IF
             y --; //should subtract 1 from the y count
             }
             }
      }

      function swapVege(obj) {
          var x=document.images;

          if (y <= 3); {

             if (x[1].src.match('Vegetables.png')) 
             {
             x[1].src=('Vegetables_Selected.png');
             y ++;
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
             }

             else if  (x[1].src.match('Vegetables_Selected.png'))
             {
             x[1].src=('Vegetables.png');
             y --;
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
             }
             }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon is unfortunate and terminates the `if` block immediately. Change (in both places)

```
if (y <= 3); {
```

to something like

```
if (y <= 3) {
```

Comment: When I do this, the image does not change at all to the "selected" version
edit: just realised what was causing this issue here: I had y start at 4

Comment: @jack Did it before? Can you edit your question to include a complete and reproducible example? Also, please don't use global variables to count *selected* items... just loop through all the items and count.

Comment: Got it all working, thanks for your tip. Such a simple mistake that I won't make again!

Answer (score 1):

if (y <= 3); {

take out the ";" here

Comment: When I do this, the image does not change at all to the "selected" version.
edit: just realised what was causing this issue here: I had y start at 4

Comment: @jack and what do you suggest?

Comment: Got it all working, thanks for your tip. Such a simple mistake that I won't make again!